# User creation form in Django

Tags: django, mixins

I am taking online Djago class and have no one to ask for help. I would appreciate to get any help and tips.

I am learning creating forms (login/singup).

So far i did in `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth


class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

In `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

I want to add addtional firelds as surname , however when i add `'surname'` in `class meta` in `fields` (`forms.py`) i get error, however the online training says i can easily add additional fields. Could you please tell what i am doing wrong and how i can add this field?

when i add those field `'surname'` in `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','surname','password1','password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['surname'].label = 'Surname'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

it give the following error:

```
raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (surname) specified for User
```

In `views.py` i ahve:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView,TemplateView
from . import forms

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the error? A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: You need to add the `surname` field to your `User` model and run `migrations`.  Then you can add the field to your `UserCreateForm`

Comment: i added the error

Comment: I can't make migrations as the terminal shows the error i posted above, it says 'surname' is unknown firleds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# In your forms.py, you need to add new field 'surname'

For Example:-
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','surname','password1','password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['surname'].label = 'Surname'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

Comment: kindly import forms from django. I have edited the code. Please check

Comment: Thank you. before i wrote from . import forms and it did not work but the documentation says . and djhango should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using the `get_user_model()` method but you are working with a custom `User` model.

In you settings set `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

Then add the `surname` field to your `User` model:

```
class User(auth.models.User):
    surname = models.Charfield()

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

Run and apply migration. Then you will be able to add the `surname` field to your form `fields`

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','surname','password1','password2')
        model = get_user_model()

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['surname'].label = 'Surname'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following changes to your `forms.py` file:-

```
from appname.models import USER 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username','email','surname','password1','password2')
        model = USER

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
        self.fields['surname'].label = 'Surname'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email Address'
```